# htaccess Allow from all wordpress index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress s2member pro, and I have a problem with the API when running this line:

```
$result = trim (file_get_contents ("http://example.com/?s2member_pro_remote_op=1", false, $post_data));
```

That I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

The only way that I have found to overcome this is to add:

```
<Files "index.php">
  Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

To the wordpress main htaccess file.

My question is whether my fix is a security risk, if so what kind of risk, and how else would you suggest me to fix this problem?

**EDIT**

Entire htaccess:

```
<Files "index.php">
  Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>

# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /team/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /team/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /team/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: what happens when you go straight to that link without using file get contents? Also is this PHP on the same server executing to itself?

Comment: Indexes under Files is meaningless